# Can we connect to LDAP using hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, orm, ldap

I wanted to understand whether we can connect Hibernate with LDAP. Tried searching for it but couldn't find a explanatory solution .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are looking forward to use LDAP as a database for your ORM i.e Hibernate, then answer is 'NO'. 
Hibernate is an ORM which requires a relational database as part of mapping whereas LDAP is just a **data store not a database** (specifically a RDBMS).

I Hope this satisy your query!

Answer (score 1):

Hibernate is an [ORM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-relational_mapping) tool, so it requires a [RDBMS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_database_management_system).

[LDAP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lightweight_Directory_Access_Protocol) is an application protocol managing a directory structure data.

So, Hibernate has no support for LDAP. The only thing close to that is the [Spring transaction manager](http://docs.spring.io/spring-ldap/docs/current/apidocs/org/springframework/ldap/transaction/compensating/manager/ContextSourceAndHibernateTransactionManager.html) support for handling both LDAP and Hibernate operations in a single unit-of-work.

Comment: Well Hibernate *can* allow persistence to MongoDB and Infinispan, so not quite correct there. And the "closest thing" would be DataNucleus JPA which DOES allow JPA persistence to LDAP (i.e no change of persistence code).

Comment: Hibernate OGM can write to MongoDB, Hibernate ORM can not. Hibernate Search can run Lucene, Hibernate ORM cannot. There are multiple Hibernate projects.

Answer (score 1):

DataNucleus JPA can connect to LDAP, using the very same JPA API. In fact it can connect to a very wide range of datastores other than RDBMS